# javascript: Creating directories from file path recursively adding timestamp to the filename

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the below code to split up a user provided path, create all intermediate dirs in the path and attach a timestamp to the ending file name. I am splitting the path with `/` first and then using `forEach` over the resulting array. Is there any better way/direct lib function to do this in javascript / nodejs.

```
function test(usrPath) {
    var locMatches = usrPath.split("/")     
    locMatches.forEach (function (item) {
        location = pathUtils.join(location,item)
        if (!fs.existsSync(location)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(location)
        }
    })      
    return pathUtils.join (location,usrPath + (new Date).toISOString().replace(/(^\d\d\d\d)|-|:|(\..*)/g,"").replace("T","_")+".log")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there are path utils that allow to make the implementation better across platform.

Also, it gives a better managed access for working with path elements like root, dir, filename and extension. `pathUtils.sep` allows working on the dir elements more cross platform.

```
var pathUtils = require('path')
function test(usrPath) {
    var pathElements = pathUtils.parse(usrPath)
    pathElements.dir.split(pathUtils.sep).forEach (function (item) {
        location = pathUtils.join(location,item)
        if (!fs.existsSync(location)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(location)
        }
    })      
    return pathUtils.join (location,pathElements.name + (new Date).toISOString().replace(/(^\d\d\d\d)|-|:|(\..*)/g,"").replace("T","_")+pathElements.ext.replace(/^$/i,".log"))
}
```